# Without any paths of includes-files for command "include" in PHP

Tags: php

I am rebuilding my very simple site because the current website is obsolete. It was made on simple HTML three years ago with one purpose - showing my photos.

I used .shtml and command *#include* for repping elements like that:

```
<!--#include virtual="/GotoUp.xml"-->
```

On the new version of my site, I decided to try PHP. But the command *include* works in a different way relative to pathways. It requires a full path to an included file relative to the current file - it isn't suitable for my site, because of it seriously complicated further change files direction.

```
<?php include './../../../Menu.php'; ?>
```

How can I change a searching algorithm that it starts to search file in the root direction?

Part of a page:

```
<body>
  <?php set_include_path ("/Menu.php") ?>  
  <?php include './../../../Metrisc/Yandex.php'; ?>    
  <div class="main">    
    <?php include './../../../Menu.php'; ?>    
    <title>Polina</title>    
    <div id="Images">
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC00750_Web.jpg" width="1200" height="1200" alt="" />
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC00820_Web.jpg" width="600" height="600" alt="" />
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC00792_Web.jpg" width="600" height="600" alt="" />
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC_2250_Web.jpg" width="600" height="900" alt="" />
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC00800_Web.jpg" width="600" height="900" alt="" />
      <img class="image" src="/Image/Portrait/Polina/DSC_2253_Web.jpg" width="1200" height="795" alt="" />
    </div>   
    <?php include './../../../Contacts.php'; ?>         
  </div>
</body>
```

[My current site](http://ivanpavlovphotograph.ru/). New version [page1](http://vanirn.bget.ru/About.php) and [page2](http://vanirn.bget.ru/PortraiteExample.php)

For clarity: **photography** is my big hobby; I am not a programmer, but I have started learning javascript and PHP for mixing English learning with something else useful and maybe to create an interactive photo-gallery in my site in next three years :)

**Update 21.10.2018.** I've created [a test page](http://vanirn.bget.ru/Image/Portrait/Polina/PolinaTestROOT.php) with the following code, and get for "getRoot()" - "../home/../vanirn/../public_html/../Portrait/../" and for 
"**DIR**" - "/home/v/vanirn/vanirntest/public_html/Image/Portrait/Polina". I think something goes wrong in the function.

```
<body>
  <?php function getRoot()
{
    $root = ROOT_DIR;
    $root = str_replace('\\', '/', $root);
    $pageroot = getcwd().'/';
    $pageroot = str_replace('\\', '/', $pageroot);
    $root = str_replace($root.'/', '', $pageroot);
    $root = preg_replace('#(/.*?).*?(/)#', '/../', '/'.$root);

    return substr($root, 1);
} ?>
  <div class="main">

    <?php echo getRoot(); ?>
    <p></p>
    <?php echo ROOT_DIR; ?>
    <p></p>
    <?php echo __DIR__; ?>

    <?php include getRoot().'Menu.php'; ?>

    <?php include './../../../Contacts.php'; ?>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the files architecture for your website? You could group your files. I suggest to use WordPress or any CMS instead of coding by yourself.

Comment: I don't want to use CMS like WordPress - It needs to learn not less than PHP for a beginning.

Comment: How can I use __DIR__, if location of "page.php" is '/home/v/vanirn/vanirntest/public_html/Image/Portrait/Polina'
and included files are located in '/home/v/vanirn/vanirntest/public_html' or one file more '/home/v/vanirn/vanirntest/public_html/includes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function for my project that you can use.

```
 /**
 * 
 * Return the root of the current page so we can call any page from any folder
 * 
 */
function getRoot(){
    $root = ROOT_DIR;
    $root = str_replace("\\", "/", $root);
    $pageroot = getcwd() ."/";
    $pageroot = str_replace("\\", "/", $pageroot);
    $root = str_replace($root."/", '' , $pageroot);
    $root = preg_replace("#(/.*?).*?(/)#", '/../', "/".$root);
    $root = substr($root, 1);
    return $root;
}
```

And then set this line on a page that is in your root folder. **Must be defined in your root folder and you must include the file that you define it in on every page that you call this function.

```
 define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

Finally you can call the function like this

```
 include getRoot()."path/to/file";
```

Basically the function will add the correct amount of ../'s to set you back to the root folder. Then you can universally set any variable based off that.

**** Update with your code ****

```
<?php

define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);

function getRoot(){
    $root = ROOT_DIR;
    $root = str_replace('\\', '/', $root);
    $pageroot = getcwd().'/';
    $pageroot = str_replace('\\', '/', $pageroot);
    $root = str_replace($root.'/', '', $pageroot);
    $root = preg_replace('#(/.*?).*?(/)#', '/../', '/'.$root);
    return substr($root, 1);
} 
?>
<body>
<div class="main">

<?php include getRoot().'Menu.php'; ?>

<?php include getRoot().'Contacts.php'; ?>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention!
So, It doesn't work. I think my knowledge is not enough...
I created a file in the root directory 'paths.php' with your function and included this file on the page.
And past other two functions.

Comment: Add the define('ROOT_DIR' , __DIR__) function at the top of that file(above the getRoot function). The include function should not go in paths.php, but instead whenever you write your <?php include "" ?>(like in your code) just append the getRoot() function in front of it.

Comment: Then you reference the file from the the root directory, and you do not have to add the ../'s manually

Comment: Ok this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found more ease solution!
Just add one stroke on ".htaccess":

php_value include_path ".:/home/v/vanirn/vanirntest/public_html/includes/:/home/v/vanirn/ivanpavlovphotograph.ru/public_html/includes/:/home/v/vanirn/ivanpavlovphotograph.ru/public_html/"
All files located in the folder "includes" will be loaded in a page. And it works in both servers test and main.